# Not in в MySQL запросе

Tags: mysql

Хотелось бы уточнить, если not in использовать в запросе, он не принесёт вреда? Просто тут как-то задавал что-то подобное и мне сказали, что NOT IN будет тормозить.

Если же использовать его это нормально, то хорошо. Если же нет, подскажите замену ему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно через "[EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188336.aspx)" попробовать. А вообще IMHO "NOT IN" не должен бы тормозить...

**UPD#1:** EXISTS возвращает TRUE если подзапрос вернул хотя бы одну строку, и FALSE - если подзапрос не вернул ни одной строки.

В вашем случае запрос будет:

```
SELECT tid FROM tasks WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tasks_done WHERE id = tid)
```

**UPD#2:** вот рабочий [пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da9e1/1)

Comment: @Rams666, а как использовать exists? у меня выдаёт, что синтаксическая ошибка:

>>SELECT `tid` FROM `tasks` WHERE `tid` EXISTS (SELECT `id` FROM `tasks_done`)

Comment: @Rams666, очень странно. Но тупо пустота, даже такое не выдаёт ничего:

>>  SELECT tasks.tid
    FROM `tasks`
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT `tdtid` FROM `tasks_done`)